# How to set $resource default api server?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to find in the angular documentation, with no success, a way of configuring the `$resource` module in order to set a server different than localhost for every request.

Something like

```
app.config(['$resourceProvider', function($resourceProvider) {
  $resourceProvider.defaults.server = "1.1.2.3:8000";
}]);
```

Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: maybe stupid question: isn't setting the host and port not something that has to be done on serverside?

Comment: the purpose is to have a static site which gets its data from a separately hosted api server

Answer (score -1):

I don't think what you're asking for makes sense in the context of `$resource`. If you look at the usage, you see things like:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
```

Here, '/user/:userId' is a URL which happens to be a relative one that resolves to whatever server the HTML page is located on.

If you want to use a third party site, simply do so:

```
var User = $resource('http://thirdpartyapi.com/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
```